# facebook like button

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

How to get the number of Likes in facebook like button?

Here is my scenario, I have five like buttons, I want to sort the buttons based on the number of likes. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get number of likes for any URL by running FQL on [`link_stat`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat) table:

```
SELECT like_count, url FROM link_stat WHERE url IN("FIRST_SHARE_URL","SECOND_SHARE_URL") ORDER BY like_count
```

then display buttons in corresponding order.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `button_count` settings which once specified, will display the counts to the right of the button.

**More Info:**

- [Like Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like)

Comment: Ok.. I already set that, what i would like to do is to get that number. Here is my scenario, I have five like buttons, I want to sort the buttons based on the number of likes. Is it possible?

Comment: @scoohh: Well, i can't figure out an easy way for that and it isn't going to be that easy what i can suspect.